Sharepoint Lists: serial number (1,2,3...) depends on creation date
Is it possible to create depedency between the row's "created at" column entry and a "serial" or "nr" entry?
I have to add rows into a List every day. I have to set a nr number (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.) for each rows a day. The currrent day is always shown in an other column, like "created day".
My idea: if I add a new row, the "serial" field should be filled out automatically, based on the set date. So, if there are 4 entries a day (1,2,3,4) for 11 July, and I delete one, it will be adjusted to (1,2,3).
And if I add a new row for 11 July, it will be added as (1,2,3,"4").
So this "serial" column should follow how many rows are added to a specific day.
Example
Is it possible somehow? If yes in JSON, could you show me an example?
Meantime I found a JSON code, which does a full serial nr list, but does not follow the days:


{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "padding": "0 3px"
      },
      "txtContent": {
        "operator": "+",
        "operands": [
          "@rowIndex",
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}



So this should be modified to watch the date in the other column.
Thank you in advance!
